# How to change phone number on Google account

Tags: google-account

How can I change my phone number on my Google account to have a different phone number with my account.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your account settings at [MyAccount](https://myaccount.google.com)
- Under "Personal Info & Privacy", click "[Your personal info](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy#personalinfo)"
- Click the right arrow (`>`) next to your current phone number(s)
- Click the pencil icons to edit your "Recovery phone" and/or, if you have one, your "Other phone"

More information about [modifying your phone number is available from Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3463280?p=modifynumber). You may need to change the phone numbers within specific apps/services as well.